# Problemas de función definida en objeto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un objeto definido mediante la librería joint que tiene como atributo una imagen "bombilla.off.jpg" la cuál me gustaría cambiar por otra mediante la función que tiene definida en el objeto (changeImage: function()). El objeto es el siguiente:

```
var light = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.define('electrics.light', {
size: {width: 80, height: 40},
attrs: {
    '.': {magnet: false},
    '.body': {width: 50, height: 25},
    '.input': {ref: '.body', 'ref-x': 1, 'ref-y': 0.5, magnet: true, port: 'in'},
    '.output': {ref: '.body', 'ref-dx': -0.5, 'ref-y': 0.5, magnet: true, port: 'out'},
    circle: {r: 5, stroke: 'black', fill: 'transparent', 'stroke-width': 1},
    image: {'xlink:href': 'bombilla.off.jpg'}}
}, {
    markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><image class="body"/></g><circle class="input"/><circle class="output"/></g>',
}, {
    changeImage: function(){
        return this.attr("image/xlink:href","bombilla.on.jpg");
    }
});
```

Se cambiar directamente la imagen del objeto con la siguiente línea de código:

```
var light_off = (new light).attr("image/xlink:href","bombilla.on.jpg");
```

Sin embargo cuando quiero cambiarla mediante el uso de la función "changeImage" no ocurre nada. La línea de código con el uso de la función es la siguiente:

```
var light_off = (new light).changeImage();
```

Me gustaría saber como tengo que definidir la función "changeImage" o como se usa para cambiar la imagen.

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] para que veamos el problema directamente en la pregunta?

Comment: La función "añadir_bombilla" añade una bombilla a un gráfico que tengo, me gustaría añadir una bombilla y cambiar su imagen ("bombilla.off.jpg" por "bombilla.on.jpg") mediante la función definida en el objeto "changeImage" y no directamente, que es lo que hace. @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has intentado algo com:

```
var light_off = changeImage(light);

changeImage: function(light)){
    return (new light).attr("image/xlink:href","bombilla.on.jpg");
}
```

Comment: he probado con tu respuesta y no me cambia la imagen del elemento, no sé en que puede estar fallando @LuiscYM